# PHP loop over checkbox issue

Tags: php, checkbox, while-loop

I get information from the database. That I list using a while loop. With this while loop, I list diseases with checkboxes. Unable to select checkboxes.

Code:

```
<li class="form-line" data-type="control_checkbox" id="id_5">
        <label class="form-label form-label-top form-label-auto" id="label_5" for="input_5"> Do you have any of the followings? (select all that apply) </label>
        <div id="cid_5" class="form-input-wide" data-layout="full">
          <div class="form-single-column" role="group" aria-labelledby="label_5" data-component="checkbox">
            
   <?php 
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "covidtmsdb");
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
   
$sql7 = "SELECT * FROM tblhealth_issues WHERE Category='disease'";
$result7 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql7);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result7) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row7 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result7)) {
                
                ?>
<span class="form-checkbox-item" style="clear:left">
              <span class="dragger-item">
              </span>
             <input type="checkbox" aria-describedby="label_5" class="form-checkbox" id="<?php  echo $row7['Question'];?>" name="ques[]" value="<?php  echo $row7['Symptoms'];?>" />
              <label id="label_input_5_0" for="input_5_0"> <?php  echo $row7['Symptoms'];?></label>
            </span>
        <?php             
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results for Q7";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>     
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please just replace label like below and check again. i hope it will work to select checkboxes.

```
<label for="<?php  echo $row7['Question'];?>"> <?php  echo $row7['Symptoms'];?></label>
```

Comment: Please try this: 
<input type="checkbox" aria-describedby="label_5" class="form-checkbox" id="<?php  echo $row7['Symptoms'];?>" name="ques[]" value="<?php  echo $row7['Symptoms'];?>" />
              <label for="<?php  echo $row7['Symptoms'];?>"> <?php  echo $row7['Symptoms'];?></label>